# How can I access data of a job submitted by a task queue in flask?

Tags: python, flask, task-queue

I have a flask web application that gets a file as input and runs some analysis on this file.

Because my python script runs for approx. 20 seconds I want it to run in the background.

A task-queue manager like redis-rq seems to be the appropriate way of dealing with this, but I want to access the data of my python script while it is running.

For example when the user starts the analysis I want to redirect him to a page where I show him the current progress of the analysis through a progress bar and also as the data structure keeps on growing I want to allow the user to display snippets of the data structure live.

Is it possible to do that with redis-rq? My understanding is, that by submitting a job you outsource the calculations to a different process, so flask itself doesn't have access to the memory space of my program.

Also as soon as the job is finished my context is lost, so I need a way of saving and constantly updating the data structure and keeping it even after the job is finished.

Comment: I've just accomplished a similar task, with a progress bar being refreshed when a user clicks for an update (on a designated button). Since I had multiple python scripts running in a background, I had each one of them write a small output to one folder. 
Additional "master" script would just "count" the number of outputs and update some log.txt file, available to Flask.
It is quite "dirty" solution, but worked fine for my needs.

Comment: Ah ok, that seems like an interesting approach. But I guess this wouldn't really suit my needs in this particular situation. Thanks though

Comment: "...but I want to access the data of my python script while it is running." No. What you do is set up a shared back end. The workers processing the task write results to shared storage (whether that be a file, a database, a queue, a memory cache, whatever) as they generates the results, and the web app reads it *on request*. Then you set up the browser to periodically send requests to the web app for updates via JS. No Python script ever shares its data with another process; they both just talk to the shared storage.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure about the communication between processes. If I understood correctly, Redis RQ is a task queue und message broker, right? So how can I tell the queued job to save the context to the message broker every 5 seconds or so?

Comment: Is it possible to set up a database so that the worker keeps on saving the result to it and I can access it with my flask application? That way I have a shared storage that keeps on growing as my program keeps on running, right?